# Plotting JMeter test results dynamically in HTML chart

Tags: jmeter

I want to be able to run a JMeter test for thousands of users and plot the results dynamically using a JQuery based charting library like HighCharts i.e. the response from every virtual user must be plotted in near real time to show a stock ticker like chart which gets updated dynamically. I am OK running the test in Non-GUI mode.

I have tried the following,
- Run the JMeter test in non-GUI mode and write the response to a file. What I notice is that the results get written to the file in a buffered manner which means even if I have a program monitoring the file for new records, I wont get it in real time.

I am looking for suggestions on how this can be achieved
1. Do I need to write a custom JMeter plugin? In this case how will it work?
2. Is there some listener which can give me the desired data
3. Can this be done via post processor?

I have seen real time reporting being done on some cloud based load testing websites which use JMeter, so I'm sure it can be done, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some buffering when writing to a file, but it shouldn't be more than a few seconds worth of data.

I'd go with the route of reading the log file into something like statsD using something like logstash.net and from there you can probably find an existing solution that pushes it to a chart.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that you work at Blazemeter. I checked it out and found that it pretty much shows a dynamic real time display of response time while the test is in progress. Is this how you do it in Blazemeter? Im guessing the blazemeter server is different from the JMeter master server. How do you get real time updates on the blazemeter server and how much of time delay do you have?

Comment: At BlazeMeter we're doing real time reading of the .jtl file using our own technology and saving it to a database. We actually ARE using an out of the box JMeter server with no modification.

Comment: @OphirPrusak please do you think you help with this question http://goo.gl/URsAFM

Answer (score 2):

You can disable buffering by adding this in user.properties file:

- jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true

This impacts slightly performances for test that have low or no pauses.

To do what you want you could use this kind of library:

- http://www.chartjs.org/

Note that since april 2023, there is a new free and open-source plugin that allows you to monitor a Non-Gui test from browser without further action.

After installing the plugin with JMeter-Plugins manager:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubik-load-pack-observability-plugin/

Just add the UbikLoadPack observality plugin (Add > Listener) to your test and you’ll be able to follow it from browser at url:

- http://server_where_jmeter_runs:9090/ulp-observability

See:

- https://github.com/ubikingenierie/ulp-observability-plugin